# Bash - find string associated with number?

Tags: bash, input, whiptail

So, my script is supposed to prompt the user which file to select using whiptail, then read some things from the user selected file. Whiptail takes 2 arguments: The number of the list entry, and the list entry itself. When the user selects a list entry, Whiptail only returns the **number** of the selection. So, my question is, how do I reference the **file** that the user selected later on in the script? This is what I have so far:

```
whiptailargs=""
num=0
for file in device-configs/*
do
echo "File is $file"
let "num += 1"
if [[ ! "$file" == *" "* ]];
then
rem="device-configs/"
rem2=" "
whiptailargs="$whiptailargs"
whiptailargs="$whiptailargs$num"
whiptailargs="$whiptailargs $file "
fi
echo "Whiptail args: $whiptailargs"
done
mode=$(whiptail --title "Example" --menu "Choose an option" 15 60 4 $whiptailargs 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
num=""
echo $mode
```

EDIT: John1024's answer worked perfectly, and he explained it very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can accomplish that with two arrays.  One array will keep the file names and the other will have the arguments that `whiptail` needs.  Because we are use arrays, not variables, this can be safe to use even if file names have spaces or other difficult characters.  Thus:

```
flist=(device-configs/*)
arglist=()
for i in "${!flist[@]}"; do
   arglist+=("$i" "${flist[i]}")
done
mode=$(whiptail --title "Example" --menu "Choose an option" 15 60 4 "${arglist[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
if [ "$mode" ]
then
    echo "$mode, ${flist[mode]}"
else
    echo "Canceled."
fi
```

#### How it works

- `flist=(device-configs/*)`

  This creates a bash array of all the names of the files of interest.  This is safe even if the names contains spaces or other difficult characters.
- `arglist=()`

  This creates an empty array.
- `for i in "${!flist[@]}"; do arglist+=("$i" "${flist[i]}"); done`

  This fills `arglist` with the values needed for `whiptail`.
- `mode=$(whiptail --title "Example" --menu "Choose an option" 15 60 4 "${arglist[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)`

  This calls `whiptail` and saves the result.  Again, the form `"${arglist[@]}"` is safe even if file names contains spaces, etc.
- `echo "$mode, ${flist[mode]}"`

  This reports the results.  We have put this in an `if` statement that detects if the user pressed cancel rather than select an answer.

Comment: @user188952 StackOverflow has some peculiar customs:  please see ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)